# how to fix overlapping of angular-gridster items while shrinking

Tags: angularjs, gridster

I am using angularjs 1.5.8 and trying to achieve angular gridster layout like this

[image]

and in mobile mode elements stack below one another. My gridster-options are as follows

```
 this.standardItems = [
        { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 0, col: 0 },  
        { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 1, col: 0 },
        { sizeX: 4, sizeY: 2, row: 0, col: 2 },
        { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 2, col: 0 },
        { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 2, col: 2 },
        { sizeX: 2, sizeY: 1, row: 2, col: 4 },
    ];

    $scope.gridsterOpts2 = {
        margins: [20, 20],
        outerMargin: false,
        swapping: false,
        pushing: false,
        rowHeight: 'match',
        mobileBreakPoint: 600,
        margins: [10, 10],
        floating: false,
        isMobile: true,
        draggable: {
            enabled: false
        },
        resizable: {
            enabled: false,
            handles: ['n', 'e', 's', 'w', 'se', 'sw']
        }
    };
```

and I have used the following style too

```
.smalltiles{
  min-height: 30%;
}

.largetile{
  min-height: 60%;
}

.gridster .gridster-item {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: #004756;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  background: blue;
  font-size: 50px;
  color:white;
}
.gridster{
  min-height:100%;
}
.gridster-item{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

The grid looks fine in desktop screen when it is resized down or in full screen the grid overlaps and elements below each other begin to overlap like this.
[image]

How do I proceed with this. Is my layouting wrong thanks in advance.

Note:
  It would be better if an example using bootstrap css classes is given

Comment: Would it be possible for you to make a demo of this?

Comment: thats the whole code for angular gridster

Comment: You can add external resources in for example https://jsfiddle.net/ . The most important would be to present your code as of now (controller etc) and give a demo people can try out and try to figure an answer for you.

Comment: Can you modify your ng-repeat etc in here https://jsfiddle.net/thepio/cerwwxd8/ ?

Comment: thanks @thepio ill modify there

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cerwwxd8/4/ i modified a bit and now its working. I could not replicate your problem. Maybe some other class from your application is messing the grid? also which browser do you use?

Comment: i was setting min-height to each column using css so that it dose not get too small even mobile mode. it is the one that is causing the problem.

Comment: I added numbers and red background, and also cannot replicate mentioned issue. @user93 which columns did you mean? gridster does not have columns

Comment: sorry, forgot to share fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/cerwwxd8/8/

Comment: you have used min-height for smalltile as 30% and largetile as 60% but those css classes seems to have no effect and it is not applied anywhere?

Comment: .smalltiles{  min-height: 30%;}
.largetile{  min-height: 60%;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally succeeded to replicate your issue by adding `ng-class="{smalltiles:item.sizeY<2,largetile:item.sizeY>1}"` to gridster item, see https://jsfiddle.net/cerwwxd8/9/, and try to move *2 (SMALL TILE)* above *3 (LARGE TILE)*. This fiddle uses `min-height` CSS rule.

here https://jsfiddle.net/cerwwxd8/10/ all `min-height` CSS rules are replaced with `height` CSS rule, and here moving *2 (SMALL TILE)* above *3 (LARGE TILE)* does not produce overlapping.

BTW: index in this fiddle is printed with `attr()` CSS function which fetches this value from the *tabindex* HTML property within *content* CSS rule:

```
.smalltiles{
  text-align: center;
  height: 30%;
}
.smalltiles:after {
  font-size: 0.5em;
  content: attr(tabindex) ' (SMALL TILE)';
}

.largetile{
  text-align: center;
  height: 60%;
}
.largetile:after {
  font-size: 0.7em;
  content: attr(tabindex) ' (LARGE TILE)'
}
```